# How to convert html string into whatsapp message format using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert below html string into recommended whatsapp message format using javascript

```
let htmlText = '<b>TEST </b> BODY <i><b>WITH </b></i>SAMPLE <strike style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">FORMAT&nbsp;</strike>&nbsp; &nbsp; HERE"';
```

into below format

```
*TEST*  BODY _*WITH *_ SAMPLE *_~FORMAT~_* HERE
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and attempt this first. If you are still stuck show us your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we will help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using a DOM Parser to parse the HTML, and then iterate over the DOM you get from it. This way the resulting text will also have all HTML entities resolved to text, any HTML comments will have been removed, and it will not break when spacing in HTML tags or their attributes is different from expected.

I would also make sure the formatting characters are put adjacent to the word they apply to, so leaving any surrounding white space out of it:

```js
function htmlToFormat(html) {
    const codes = { B: "*", I: "_", STRIKE: "~" };
    const {body} = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlText, "text/html");
    const dfs = ({childNodes}) => Array.from(childNodes, node => {
        if (node.nodeType == 1) {
            const s = dfs(node);
            const code = codes[node.tagName];
            return code ? s.replace(/^(\s*)(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(\s*)$/g, `$1${code}$2`) : s;
        } else {
            return node.textContent;
        }
    }).join("");

    return dfs(body);
}

// Demo
let htmlText = '<b>TEST </b> BODY <i><b>WITH </b></i>SAMPLE <strike style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">FORMAT&nbsp;</strike>&nbsp; &nbsp; HERE"';
console.log(htmlToFormat(htmlText));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @trincot solution, added some additional changes

```
function htmlToFormat(htmlText) {
  const matches = htmlText.matchAll(/<i><b>(.*?)<\/b><\/i>/g);
  for (const match of matches) {
    if (match[1]) {
      htmlText = htmlText.replace(match[0], `<b><i>${match[1]}</i></b>`);
    }
  }
  // format strike text
  let strikeArr = htmlText.match(/<strike(.*?)<\/strike>/g);
  if (strikeArr.length) {
    for (let i=0;i< strikeArr.length; i++) {
      if (strikeArr[i]) {
        strikeText = strikeArr[i].match(/style="(.*?)">/g);
        if (strikeText.length) {
          let strikeTextSplit = strikeText[0].split(";");
          let italicStatus = false;
          let boldStatus = false;
          let trimedText = strikeArr[i].replace(/\s*\S*\="[^"]+"\s*/gm, "");
          for (let j=0; j< strikeTextSplit.length; j++) {
            if (strikeTextSplit[j].includes("italic")) {
              italicStatus = true;
            }
            if (strikeTextSplit[j].includes("bold")) {
              boldStatus = true;
            }
          }
          if (italicStatus) {
            trimedText = `<i>${trimedText}</i>`;
          }
          if (boldStatus) {
            trimedText = `<b>${trimedText}</b>`
          }
          htmlText = htmlText.replace(strikeArr[i], trimedText);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const codes = { B: "*", I: "_", STRIKE: "~" };
  const { body } = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlText, "text/html");
  const dfs = ({ childNodes }) => Array.from(childNodes, node => {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      const s = dfs(node);
      const code = codes[node.tagName];
      return code ? s.replace(/^(\s*)(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(\s*)$/g, `$1${code}$2`) : s;
    } else {
      return node.textContent;
    }
  }).join("");

  return dfs(body);
}

let htmlText = '<b>TEST </b> BODY <i><b>WITH </b></i>SAMPLE <strike style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">FORMAT&nbsp;</strike>&nbsp; &nbsp; HERE"';
console.log(htmlToFormat(htmlText));
```